# Difference between TFS 2012 and TFS 2013 process templates

Tags: tfs

We are planning to upgrade from Tfs 2012 to Tfs 2013. Can anyone help me understand the difference in process templates between them? We use all three process templates for different projects.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The changes are very minor, except for:

- The introduction of Portfolio backlogs.
- Test Plans and test Suites are now Work Item Types (TFS 2013 update 3).
- The AgileConfig and CommonProcessConfig files have been merged to a single file inside the template

The minor changes:

- Git support for the Source Control options
- Stackrank type fields are now hidden by default (because Agile task boards are now features of the Standard CAL).
- Tag field support through the API.

The easiest way to visualize all differences is by comparing them through the [TFS Team Project Manager](http://www.edsquared.com/2012/03/08/Comparing+TFS+Process+Templates+Across+Team+Projects.aspx) which [can be downloaded here](http://teamprojectmanager.codeplex.com/).

Comment: jessehouwing: Thanks for you response. It is really helpful.

Comment: jessehouwing: Are Backlog Priority fields also hidden by default like Stackrank type fields?

Comment: They are in the 2013.3 template.

Answer (score 0):

TFS 2013 did not work well with our existing workspaces defined on remote network drives. TFS 2012 did work with this configuration.

After working several hours with our System Administrators, we gave up on trying to get the trying to get the existing network drive workspaces to work with the TFS 2013. Converting the workspaces to local drive locations enabled us to work with TFS 2013.